# Add column with default in postgresql without table level lock

Tags: postgresql

Have such a problem - table with over 20mln rows.

When i add new column with default - postgresql lock table for over 40 minutes so my application stop working for this time.

So instead of

```
ALTER TABLE "test" ADD COLUMN "field" boolean DEFAULT True NOT NULL;
```

I do

```
ALTER TABLE "test" ADD COLUMN "field" boolean NULL;
ALTER TABLE "test" ALTER COLUMN "field" SET DEFAULT true;
```

after which every new row will be with true by default, so now I need to update 20mln current rows.

I update them in batches:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id as pk
FROM "test"
WHERE  "field" is null
LIMIT  10000
)
UPDATE "test" table_
SET "field" = true
FROM   cte
WHERE  table_.id = cte.pk
```

after which i do

```
ALTER TABLE "test" ALTER COLUMN "field" SET NOT NULL;
```

And everything is alright but when I update rows is too slow. Can you give my some advice about improving speed of update?

Currently it update 10000 in about 2 minutes.
I try decreasing size to 1000 - it was better (3.5 minutes for 10000) but it still to slow.

I also try create index before update, but it doesnt give better results (as i understand it will give better result but when huge path of table will be updated).

Answer (score 3):

You can speed up `UPDATE`s with [HOT](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD). That requires that the updated column is not indexed (easy in your case) and that there is free space in the table blocks (`fillfactor` < 100). Not sure if you meet the second requirement.

Another thing to improve the speed of bulk updates is to increase `max_wal_size` so that checkpoints don't occur often.

Maybe you can wait a few months for [PostgreSQL v11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/release-11.html). The following new feature would do what you need:

> - Allow `ALTER TABLE` to add a column with a non-null default without a table rewrite (Andrew Dunstan, Serge Rielau)